# custom numberfield does not validate against NaN

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Unfortunately Vuetify does not provide number inputs yet. I tried to create one on my own.

The user is able to validate fields using regex patterns. A basic example would be to check if the current field is empty.

If so my Numberfield component will return `NaN` because the field value can't get parsed to a number. The validation is not able to check if the field is empty because `NaN` does not mean empty.

I also tried to return "nothing" with this

```
  if (isNaN(number)) {
    this.$emit("input");
  } else {
    this.$emit("input", number);
  }
```

but the validation still does not return an error. My number field component:

```
<template>
  <v-text-field :value="value" type="Number" :required="required" :rules="rules" @input="input"></v-text-field>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    value: {
      required: true
    },
    required: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    rules: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    input: function(newValue) {
      const number = parseFloat(newValue);
      this.$emit("input", number);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

When consuming the component I use this sample code

```
<template>
  <NumberField :value="number" :required="true" :rules="numberRules" @input="updateNumber"/>
</template>

<script>
import NumberField from "../components/NumberField";

export default {
  components: {
    NumberField
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      number: 12345,
      pattern: /.*\S.*/
    };
  },
  computed: {
    numberRules: function() {
      return [() => this.pattern.test(this.number) || "this is invalid"];
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateNumber: function(newValue) {
      this.number = newValue;

      console.log(newValue);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

I also created an example where you can play around:

https://codesandbox.io/s/number-input-validation-hiz2u

What to return if the value is `NaN` might be opinionbased. But how can I trigger the validation for that field when empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two mistakes in your code:

1. You forgot to specify that the pattern is a regex
2. Your regex will basically match anything

I corrected the regex and added the correct javascript object:

```
data: function() {
    return {
      number: 12345,
      pattern: new RegExp("^\d+$")
    };
  },
```

Codesandbox doesn't let us escape `\d`, so you can test with `[0-9]+` instead of `\d` in codesandbox.

I don't know what input you want to allow exactly, but you can elaborate your regex using [regex101](https://regex101.com/).